# angular: Showing mongodb keys of one document

Tags: angularjs

I have the following code in my html:

```
  <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend">
            <input type="text" ng-model="friend[key]">     
        </span>
        <button ng-click="save(friend)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
  </li>
```

Producing this input fields as output (receiving data from MongoDB via the Controller Resolver)

```
[value1] [value2] [value3]

[value1] [value2] [value3]
```

What would you do to achieve this html output:

```
key1     key2     key3

[value1] [value2] [value3]

[value1] [value2] [value3]
```

What is the meaning of this? I want to achieve a Excel-File like output on a Web page. The  controller "serves" the friend model to the html. In other words key1, key2, key3 is the schema of my mongdb database.

Adding this in front of the previous code would work:

```
 <li ng-repeat="friend in friends">
        <span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friend">
            {{key}}    
        </span>
  </li>
```

..but iterates through my whole collection and also produces all keys of all documents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want an excel-like table, you should consider [ng-grid](http://angular-ui.github.io/ng-grid/).

With your data being an array of documents (friends), it would work just fine. The most basic ng-grid example represents just that :

```
$scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                 {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                 {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                 {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                 {name: "Enos", age: 34}];
```

Otherwise, you can just cheat by doing :

```
//Remove the first ng-repeat so you don't cycle through all the data
<span ng-repeat="(key, value) in friends[0]">
    {{key}}    
</span>
```

bmleite's answer is better if you want to make your own table

Comment: Nice, didn't know about ng-grid. Now consider my schema-less documents to be like this: {"current" { name: "Moroni", age: 50}, "history" : { "1" : {"content"}}}. Would it be possible to access the data in the current object literal through ng-grid as well? Or better DIY?

Comment: You can access sub-documents in ng-grid using the column definition : `{field: 'current.name', displayName : 'Name'}`. You can find examples on the main ng-grid page.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a table?

Define your schema on the controller, like this:

```
$scope.schema: [
    "Auftragsnr",
    "Bonusposition",
    "Geschaeftsfeld",
    "Positionnr"
];
```

and on the HTML:

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th ng-repeat="column in schema" ng-bind="column"></th>
      <th>buttons</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr ng-repeat="friend in friends">
      <td ng-repeat="prop in schema">
        <input type="text" ng-model="friend[prop]">
      </td>
      <td>
        <button ng-click="save(friend)" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/YglfOdZPy5Ub90Ouj5XG?p=preview)